# Mesh gets physically distorted when rendering in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, distort

As you can see in the image below, the lid on a jam of jar I modeled seems to distort whenever I put the mesh into cycles rendering. Then, when I put it back to material preview, it goes back to normal. Please help me fix this. Thanks! :)

[image]

.blend File: https://we.tl/t-B98ueKL8n0

Comment: Any modifiers or displacement applied?

Comment: @brockmann I don't believe so, except for maybe a subdiv... but that isn't actually on the lid itself.

Comment: Did you plug something into the displacement input of the "Material Output" node (the last one) in your shader editor ?

Comment: Suggest share a file @MmmChezBurgerz

Comment: @brockmann There you go! :)

Comment: @Gorgious I don't believe so, no. I don't remember needing to use displacement at all. :)

Comment: Georges is right, the shader has displacement. Either disconnect it or lower the value.

Comment: @Gorgious Good guess, you should convert that comment into an answer.

Comment: @brockmann Ohhh, I see where now. I forgot that I imported a texture from Textures.one using Lilysurfacescrapper and that it'd automatically give it a displacement. Ty. :)

Comment: @Gorgious Thankyou too! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure there is nothing plugged into the "Displacement" output of your material shader.
Alternatively you can also disable the true displacement within the material properties, but this might leave the artifacts as a bump.

[image]